# Is is more appropriate to salute the organization, or the members of the organization?

Tags: letter-writing, salutations

I am writing a thank-you letter for a scholarship I received from the AFCEA – Bethesda Chapter. I am not sure how to write the salutation though. Two alternatives I have considered are:

> Dear AFCEA Bethesda Chapter:

and

> Dear members of the AFCEA Bethesda Chapter:

I am not sure which, if either, would be the most appropriate, or if there is a better option I am not seeing.

How should I write the salutation for my letter?

Further research examining past thank-you letters has been inconclusive. Many of them use extremely informal salutations, and there are as many different salutations as letters. You can see them [here](http://www.afceabethesda.org/philanthropy/default.aspx), if you really want to.

Comment: If you worked with someone specific then direct it at them and thank the other members as well. If not then I would say either works, it just depends what you are trying to convey.

Comment: **Members** sounds and looks better to me.

Comment: In 'BrE', it is common to use a collective noun metonymically: 'The team were arguing amongst themselves' (= 'The members of the team were arguing amongst themselves'). This is true also of proper-noun groups. However, even people who are quite happy with this convention would probably find 'Dear AFCEA Bethesda Chapter' a little impersonal. I'd certainly choose 'Dear members of the AFCEA Bethesda Chapter' in spite of its clunkiness.

Comment: I'm with user3306356 and Ashworth: You are a thankful person writing to other people. The abstract organization will consider itself suitable thanked.

Answer (score 2):

Since the scholarship is given by the chapter, you must address the chapter itself. The members are only a part of the chapter. The scholarship was given by the institution, and the members by themselves do not make it up - the institution also includes its history, its goals, its mottos, etc.